# Pass string into ns3::Ipv4AddressHelper::SetBase method

Tags: c++, network-programming, modeling, ns-3

Topology helper `Ipv4AddressHelper` allows to set the base address as shown in the example.

```
Ipv4AddressHelper address;
address.SetBase ("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");
```

I want store an arbitrary number of addresses dynamically created, for example.

```
  ...
  for( uint32_t subnetC = 0; subnetC < nSubnets; subnetC++ )
  {    
     string ip = "10.1." + lexical_cast< string >( subnetC + 1 ) +".0";
     ipList.push_back( ip );
  }
  ...
  vIpv4AddressHelper[ someIndex ].SetBase(ipList[ someIndex ], "255.255.255.0" );
  ...
```

However, I get the error

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘ns3::Ipv4AddressHelper::SetBase(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, const char [14])’
 note: candidates are: void ns3::Ipv4AddressHelper::SetBase(ns3::Ipv4Address, ns3::Ipv4Mask, ns3::Ipv4Address)
```

How do I pass a string to `SetBase` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tells you that the candidate needs 2 params (the third one is optional. Also, see the [doc for Ipv4AdressHelper](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen-release/classns3_1_1_ipv4_address_helper.html)). So pass those params.
In the [docs](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen-release/classns3_1_1_ipv4_address.html) you can see that `Ipv4Adress` can be constructed with a `char const*`. So try:

```
address.SetBase (ns3::Ipv4Adress(adress_string.c_str()), ns3::Ipv4Mask(mask_string.c_str()));
```

Changing `adress_string` and `mask_string` accordingly to your needs.

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for the corrections, I'll change the post right away!